# hasMany relationships return Undefined property

Tags: laravel

I like to list all `MovimentoProdutoUnidade` that `movimento_id = 3` using the `hasMany` function.

My Model `Movimento`:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Unidade;

class Movimento extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
    "movimento", "descricao", "requisitante", "despachante", "data", "unidade_ori_id", "unidade_des_id"
    ];
    protected $table = "movimentos";

    public function movimentoProdutoUnidade(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\MovimentoProdutoUnidade', 'movimento_id');
    }
}
```

My Model `MovimentoProdutoUnidade`

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Movimento;

class MovimentoProdutoUnidade extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        "movimento_id", "unidadeProduto_id"
    ];
    protected $table = "movimento_produtounidades";

    public function movimento(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Movimento', 'movimento_id');
    }
}
```

My Controller:

```
public function licitacao(Request $request){
    $movimentos = Movimento::where('unidade_ori_id', 3)->movimentoProdutoUnidade;

    dd($movimentos);

    //return view('relatorios.licitacao', compact('movimentos'));
}
```

The `dd` fuction return

> Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::$movimentoProdutoUnidade

Comment: try using `first` function like this  `Movimento::where('unidade_ori_id', 3)->first()->movimentoProdutoUnidade`

Comment: have you initialized  movimentoProdutoUnidade in your contructer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is because you're not calling `first()` on the query builder object, so you have an instance of `Builder` (which does not have a `$movimentoProdutoUnidade` property) instead of a `Movimento` model:

```php
$movimento = Movimento::where('unidade_ori_id', 3)->first();
$movimento_produto_unidade = $movimento->movimentoProdutoUnidade;
```

However, if you want all `MovimentoProdutoUnidade`, try thinking "backwards":

```php
$movimento_produto_unidade = MovimentoProdutoUnidade::whereHas('movimento', function ($query) {
  return $query->where('unidade_ori_id', 3);
})
->get();
```

Comment: I need filter `$movimento_produto_unidade = MovimentoProdutoUnidade::whereHas('movimento.unidade_ori_id', function ($query) { return $query->whereId(3); })` but the filter `3` is on column and not on id

Comment: I updated the answer with the column you're trying to use, does that work?

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the comment i made, try using `first` function like this:

`Movimento::where('unidade_ori_id', 3)->first()->movimentoProdutoUnidade;`

Remember always after the condition use `get()`, `first()` or `find()`  functions to pull the data from the database.

Take a look to this [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#retrieving-models)

Comment: I use first but not get all records. How to use get()?

Comment: Considering that the answer provided by @Travis has a solution. Read this link https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations